# SQL How to make 1to1 match on join with multiple possibilities

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm not too sure how to word this quite correctly. I have 2 tables that match on multiple columns, but have different values in other columns. I need to have the  query choose just one matching pair. I've included some example sql to test.

```
   CREATE TABLE TEST1 
   (    
    LVL1 NUMBER, 
    LVL2 NUMBER, 
    LVL3 NUMBER, 
    DESCR VARCHAR2(30 BYTE)
   );

   CREATE TABLE TEST2 
   (    
    LVL1 NUMBER, 
    LVL2 NUMBER, 
    LVL3 NUMBER, 
    CID NUMBER
   );

   insert into test1 (lvl1, lvl2, lvl3, descr) values (101, 1, 1, 'lackadaisical'); 
   insert into test1 (lvl1, lvl2, lvl3, descr) values (101, 1, 1, 'martially'); 
   insert into test1 (lvl1, lvl2, lvl3, descr) values (101, 1, 2, 'brian'); 
   insert into test1 (lvl1, lvl2, lvl3, descr) values (101, 2, 1, 'symploce'); 
   insert into test1 (lvl1, lvl2, lvl3, descr) values (101, 2, 2, 'prismatoid'); 
   insert into test1 (lvl1, lvl2, lvl3, descr) values (101, 2, 3, 'delirious'); 
   insert into test1 (lvl1, lvl2, lvl3, descr) values (102, 1, 1, 'discontinuous'); 
   insert into test1 (lvl1, lvl2, lvl3, descr) values (102, 2, 1, 'subseptate'); 
   insert into test1 (lvl1, lvl2, lvl3, descr) values (102, 2, 1, 'heterodox'); 
   insert into test1 (lvl1, lvl2, lvl3, descr) values (102, 2, 1, 'liege'); 
   insert into test1 (lvl1, lvl2, lvl3, descr) values (103, 1, 1, 'mobbish'); 


   insert into test2 (lvl1, lvl2, lvl3, cid) values (101, 1, 1, 10); 
   insert into test2 (lvl1, lvl2, lvl3, cid) values (101, 1, 1, 15); 
   insert into test2 (lvl1, lvl2, lvl3, cid) values (101, 1, 2, 20); 
   insert into test2 (lvl1, lvl2, lvl3, cid) values (101, 2, 1, 25); 
   insert into test2 (lvl1, lvl2, lvl3, cid) values (101, 2, 2, 30); 
   insert into test2 (lvl1, lvl2, lvl3, cid) values (101, 2, 3, 35); 
   insert into test2 (lvl1, lvl2, lvl3, cid) values (102, 1, 1, 40); 
   insert into test2 (lvl1, lvl2, lvl3, cid) values (102, 2, 1, 45); 
   insert into test2 (lvl1, lvl2, lvl3, cid) values (102, 2, 1, 50); 
   insert into test2 (lvl1, lvl2, lvl3, cid) values (102, 2, 1, 55); 
   insert into test2 (lvl1, lvl2, lvl3, cid) values (103, 1, 1, 60);
```

So, each table contains 11 rows that match on lvl1, lvl2, and lvl3. I need the query to return 11 rows. It doesn't matter which descr is matched to which cid, although it would be nice to put a priority based on other columns.

Running the below query returns 19 rows with each possibility of descr and cid combinations for each lvl1,lvl2,lvl3 match.

```
   select 
     t1.lvl1,
     t1.lvl2,
     t1.lvl3,
     t1.descr,
     t2.cid
   from
     test1 t1,
     test2 t2
   where
     t2.lvl1 = t1.lvl1 and
     t2.lvl2 = t1.lvl2 and
     t2.lvl3 = t1.lvl3;




   LVL1       LVL2       LVL3       DESCR                                 CID
   ---------- ---------- ---------- ------------------------------ ----------
    101          1          1       martially                              10
    101          1          1       lackadaisical                          10
    101          1          1       martially                              15
    101          1          1       lackadaisical                          15
    101          1          2       brian                                  20
    101          2          1       symploce                               25
    101          2          2       prismatoid                             30
    101          2          3       delirious                              35
    102          1          1       discontinuous                          40
    102          2          1       liege                                  45
    102          2          1       heterodox                              45
    102          2          1       subseptate                             45
    102          2          1       liege                                  50
    102          2          1       heterodox                              50
    102          2          1       subseptate                             50
    102          2          1       liege                                  55
    102          2          1       heterodox                              55
    102          2          1       subseptate                             55
    103          1          1       mobbish                                60

   19 rows selected
```

**Edit**
I can't have any duplicates in either the descr or cid columns for each match. for example lvls 101-1-1 has 2 cid matches (10,15) to 2 descr (lackadaisical, martially) i would need 2 rows for 101-1-1 where each descr is paired; (lackadaisical, 10 and martially, 15) or (lackadaisical, 15 and martially, 10).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `row_number` to number the rows and get only one of them for each combination.

```
select * from (
select 
 t1.lvl1,
 t1.lvl2,
 t1.lvl3,
 t1.descr,
 t2.cid,
 row_number() over(partition by t1.lvl1,t1.lvl2,t1.lvl3,t1.descr order by t2.cid) as rnum
from
 test1 t1 
join test2 t2 on t2.lvl1 = t1.lvl1 and t2.lvl2 = t1.lvl2 and t2.lvl3 = t1.lvl3
) t 
 where rnum = 1
```

Prioritize them if needed by modifying the `order by` in `row_number`.

Comment: This is pretty close, but I failed to specify in my question that I can't have any duplicates in either the descr or cid columns for each match. for example lvls 101-1-1 has 2 cid matches (`10,15`) to 2 descr (`lackadaisical, martially`) i would need 2 rows for 101-1-1 where each descr is paired; (`lackadaisical, 10` and `martially, 15`) or (`lackadaisical, 15` and `martially, 10`).